# change 240 breaker to 120

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have several spare 240 breakers in my panel box. I'm adding 8 outlets from 2 different rooms.  Can I use half of the 240 breaker instead of replacing with a 120, or should I pull the 240 and replace with a 120? One of the spare 240's has wires coming out but are no longer in use (for old baseboard heat).

Comment: ?hat size breakers and 8 outlets for two rooms on one circuit?? What wire size?

Comment: What make and model are your existing breakers?

Comment: You may also want to research Multi Wire Branch Circuits (MWBC) which use "240v" breakers to make two 120v circuits.  You get two safe circuits that share a neutral wire.

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses.  My existing single pole breakers are 20amp "D", type E.  The 2 poles are "D" issue no. RT-1372.  If that answers your question.  Wire size: 12/2 (That's what I had)

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing breakers please?

Comment: How do I post photos?

Comment: @Joel -- hit the [edit] link on your post (bottom left, in the "share edit ...", then use the "mountain and sun" button in the toolbar to edit the photos in

Comment: Ok. I've tried to drag/drop, copy/paste, and browse.  My pics won't upload.  Using browse it says the file is too big.  Not sure what to do.  There are several different breakers installed.  I see square D type HOM RT500 06P, then square D (in yellow) with the number 61 enclosed in a box.  Then there's Siemens  type QP L-5338.  Those are the singles.  The doubles are all square D

Answer (score 4):

You can use either or both halves as separate single pole circuits as long as the amperage rating is correct for the wire size and receptacle type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The only issue you'll get into is if your nation's electrical code requires a higher grade of breaker.  For instance most breakers in the USA or Canada need to be AFCI type.  You'd be better off with single AFCIs rather than fooling around with a 2-pole AFCI.

In some cases, both AFCI and GFCI is required (or desirable) and in that case an AFCI+GFCI dual-mode breaker is cheaper than an AFCI breaker + GFCI recep(s).

If AFCI is required you cannot use an AFCI recep unless you run metal conduit.